# Are there any languages that handle functional impurity (side effects) without modeling them as RealWorld or IO?

Tags: functional-programming, side-effects, io-monad

One thing that always bothered me in Haskell (and other functional languages, for that matter) is that the entire language is pure, but side-effects are indirectly allowed by using an object that represents the entire "real world" (the IO monad, for example).

I wonder, are there languages that handle this without modeling the entire world? For example, representing network input as a byte array that is lazily filled as the network input is read.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell itself was specified to use something like you describe before `IO` (the monad) was invented, under the name *dialogues*.  The following example is from [Imperative functional programming](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/158511.158524) (the seminal paper on `IO`) by Peyton Jones and Wadler, 1993:

```hs
type Dialogue = [Response] -> [Request]
main :: Dialogue

data Request = Putc Char | Getc
data Response = OK | OKCh Char

echo :: Dialogue
echo resps = Getc :
             if (a == eof)
             then []
             else Putc a : 
                  echo (drop 2 resps)
           where
             OKCh a = resps !! 1
```

It is preceded by the explanation:

> The I/O system specifed for the Haskell language (Hudak et al. [1992])
>   is based on dialogues, also called lazy streams (Dwelly [1989];
>   O'Donnell [1985]; Thompson [1989]). In Haskell, the value of the
>   program has type `Dialogue`, a  synonym for a function between a list
>   of I/O responses to a list of I/O requests.

and concluded with some difficulties:

- It is easy to extract the wrong element of the responses, a *synchronisation error*,
- The `Response` data type has to contain a constructor for every possible response to every request, and
- even more seriously, the style is not composable.

Comment: It's funny that `IO` is therefore exactly as old as I am. So no, I cannot speak from historic experience there :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never really liked the real world analogy. I think it's popular because most people's first exposure to parametric polymorphism is containers, so their brain wants to know what an `IO` "contains." Really, it contains a lazily-evaluated sort of syntax tree data structure that is later interpreted to produce the side effects it describes, but that data structure isn't exposed to the user except through the much more abstract `IO` type.

At any rate, aside from @phipsgabler's excellent answer about what Haskell previously used, some kind of `IO` type is used pretty much everywhere people want pure FP nowadays. However, it's a sort of low-level, edge of your program abstraction. Many abstractions are built on top of it.

One example is functional reactive programming, which has several variations, but basically sets up streams of events over time. Elm has a command/subscription model.

Also, libraries usually set up abstractions that make sense for their domain, like web services are often modeled as a function that is called with a `Request` object and returns an `IO` of a `Response` object. Further down the stack from that function, where side effects aren't needed, your interface is just pure types, like a function that takes a `User` object and returns HTML for that user's profile.

But at some point, whether you call it an `IO` or a `Command` or an `Observable`, it all boils down to the very powerful idea of separating the specification of what side effects you want from the actual execution of those effects. The form may differ, but the fundamental concept isn't going away anytime soon.